# Delete all files AND subfolders in a parent folder in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the below script - which finds all the files in a folder (including files in subfolders) and deletes them, however, I want this script to delete all the folders in the parent folder as well. So basically the entire contents of the parent folder are wiped.

```
    function DeleteInvoices() {
  const getAllFiles = folder => {
    const files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      const file = files.next();
      console.log(file.getName());
      file.setTrashed(true);
    }
    const folders = folder.getFolders();
    while (folders.hasNext()) getAllFiles(folders.next());
  }

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1-2VAPBzEQxCaoN7KGSB_K_peiLIDk32e");
  getAllFiles(folder);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Do you want to delete the parent fodler itself or only its contents?

Answer (score 0):

- To trash the files and folders contained in a parent folder, you only need to iterate through the first level
- Nested files and folders will be automatically trashed if their parent folder is trashed
- The method [setTrashed(trashed)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#settrashedtrashed)  is not only available for files, but also for folders

### Working sample:

```
function DeleteAllContents() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1-2VAPBzEQxCaoN7KGSB_K_peiLIDk32e");
  const files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()){
    var file = files.next();
    file.setTrashed(true); 
  }
  const folders = folder.getFolders();
  while (folders.hasNext()){
    var folder = folders.next();
    folder.setTrashed(true); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I tried the code but I get this error: 
ReferenceError: folders is not defined

Comment: Sorry about this - somehow one line went missing :-)